# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently posted this question: [How do recovery tools like Cellebrite work and can they recover data from phones which utilize Full Disk Encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225318/how-do-recovery-tools-like-cellebrite-work-and-can-they-recover-data-from-phones?noredirect=1#comment460556_225318)

Quite simply, I read through the Help Center and it clearly states "security tools" are **on-topic** for Information Security. In fact, the Help Center does make it clear that the discussion needs to involve "protecting assets."

Firstly, I am an Information Security professional - I get paid to do InfoSec. Secondly, I would consider Cellebrite tools to be in the realm of "Information Security" for precisely the reason that if I dropped my cell phone on the street, and an *unauthorized individual* retrieved it, he/she could potentially use tools like Cellebrite to violate the **confidentiality** ([ref](https://www.forcepoint.com/cyber-edu/cia-triad)) of my data/electronically stored information. **This would be an information security issue.**

As a security engineer with a company that develops mobile devices & software, this question was an attempt to learn ways in which tools such as Cellebrite operate, to help mitigate the risk of the aforementioned scenario, amongst others.

Can someone explain to me how this is off-topic as described the Help Center, and how it could be edited to be re-opened?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is an "information security" tool, but it is also closed source and by its nature, very secretive.

So, "how it works" is a question for the company.